# UWP- ItemsControl vs ListView?

Tags: image, listview, binding, win-universal-app, itemscontrol

I'm building a page on a universal windows project, and since I'm in the process of learning I used a listview for everything. On this particular page, I don't want the elements to be selectable, but I also don't want all of the text/images to be grayed out.

I found a setter property for a listviewitem "ishittestvisible" that allows me to disable it, and for now that's what I'm using. However I feel like it might be better practice to use an ItemsControl since by default you can't interact with it.

The problem is in one of my images, though. In my viewmodel I'm pulling data from a test database, and one piece of data happens to be an invalid URL to an image source. When I use the ListView, this is handled gracefully and I get an empty block where the image should be. When I use an ItemsControl, however. the app crashes. I have attempted to use the "Image_Failed" event for the Image, but the app appears to crash before this event is ever called.

Does anybody have an idea of what might be going on here? And am I correct in the assumption that using an ItemsControl would be preferable or should I just stick with my working ListView solution?

Comment: could you plase left your code?

Comment: If you want a very simple non-selectable with a few items, you can go with `ItemsControl`; otherwise, always use a `ListView` which supports item selection, data virtualiazation and a lot more. If you don't want the items to be selectable, simply set `SelectionMode="None"` on the `ListView`.

Comment: That's a start, Justin, good to know that it's preferable that way. The more pressing question is what is different about the ListView that allows it to gracefully handle an invalid image URL, while the ItemsControl crashes the app before it throws an exceptions that I'm able to handle?

Comment: For you needs just stick with `ListView`. Also `ItemsControl` shoud be used as `ItemsPanel` in `ListView` (that is default  for `ListView` actually). And if you want filter broken images just modify `ItemTemplate` and use `Converter` for `Visibility`. If you'll show your XAML and code I could help you with that.